# How to get Unique ID for a group of dropDowns generated by a loop?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts-1, scriptlet, struts-tags

Please Help me here to solve below problem.

Code:

```
<%for(int ind=0;ind<15;ind++){%>

 <tr>
   <struts-el:select name="OpEnh01pagSincomModelMaintanenceFormBean" property="mdlCode" styleId="mdlDrpDown_+'<%=ind %>'" onchange="modelCodeChanged(this.id)">
     <struts-el:options collection="listmodelCodes" property="modelCode" labelProperty="modelCodeDesc" />
   </struts-el:select> 
 </tr>

<%}%>
```

1) I want 15 dropdowns in 15 rows. I want dropDown's index to identify which dropDown is modified in JavaScript.

2) I want to get a unique id so that I can access it using dom in JavaScript called by onChangeEvent.

I have a form bean Name properties mdlDrpDown1, mdlDrpDown2 and so on..

I tried this format: `styleId="mdlDrpDown_+'<%=ind %>'"` but couldn't get it as styleId, property attribute are not runTimeExpr.

Comment: onchange passes `this.id` but there is no id attribute set.

Comment: Actually in generated html. "styleId" attribute is converted to "id" attribute. Hence I used this.id as parameter to JS.
But my main problem is i cant get the loopIndex in the property or StyleID attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using dynamic property names `mdlCode<%=ind %>` for `select`, if getter and setter are not found in the formbean then `No getter method Exception will be raised`, to avoid this we can `index based properties` (which can holds multiple values based on index, index value will order of the elements appear in the page) instead of `single properties` (which can holds only one value).

Try the below code:

FormBean:

```
//create getter and setter for `mdlCode` using String[], so it can hold dynamic values.

String[] mdlCode;

public String[] getMdlCode() {
   return mdlCode;
}
public void setMdlCode(String[] mdlCode) {
   this.mdlCode=mdlCode;
}
```

JSP:

```
<%for(int ind=0;ind<15;ind++) {
    String id = "mdlDrpDown_"+ind;
%>

<tr>
    <!-- change property from `property="mdlCode<%=ind %>"` to property='mdlCode' -->
    <struts-el:select name="OpEnh01pagSincomModelMaintanenceFormBean" property="mdlCode" styleId="<%=id %>" onchange="modelCodeChanged(this.id)">
        <struts-el:options collection="listmodelCodes" property="modelCode" labelProperty="modelCodeDesc" />
    </struts-el:select> 
</tr>

<%}%>
```

Comment: I tried and got error:
JSPG0124E: Custom tag attribute styleId cannot be runtime expression. value: "[%=id %]"

Comment: Now i changed the styleId="const" 
a **constant** >> Page loaded and Now the generated html for all select elements has :
**name="mdlCode" id="const" **


1)the modification of property attribute is not helpful.


2)styleID **cannot have any rutime expressions in it**. so i cant get scriptlet <%=ind %> evaluated here.

Comment: @SalmanParacha: Can you check this once.

this question is similar to your earlier post:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5970295/how-to-append-loop-index-of-cforeach-tag-to-struts-html-tag-attributes)

Comment: @Vishnu300 i tired the same code in struts-1.3 and tomcat its working for me. which version of strtuts you are using and server?

Comment: What is the generated html for select tag ( id and name attributes) in your case ?
Struts 1.1 and IBM WAS 6.1 are the versions used.

Comment: when directly used  `<%=ind %>` it is not evaluated, when created separate variable (`id`) the output came as expected, i.e. `mdlDrpDown_1` ... .

Comment: Is it version specific ? Cant get in my configuration..
@Srinu: Any Idea ?

Comment: @Vishnu300 I checked it with `struts 1.1` also, its working same as `struts1.3`. May be the problem is with your server. once check with that.

Comment: @Vishnu300 Which `taglib` you are using? I'm using `<%@ taglib prefix="struts-el" uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-html" %>` for `select`

Comment: @Vishnu300 once check with `tld file` for `<attribute>
<name>styleId</name>
<required>false</required>
<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>` under `<tag><name>select</name>` in this `<rtexprvalue>` must be `true`, they only run time values can be evaluated.

Comment: indexed ID is coming now.my **taglib uri is different** earlier whose styleID attribute has **rtexprvalue-false**.
Now i modified and its working. **Thanks alot @Srinu for all the help.**

Comment: generated html is:
**<select name="mdlCode" onchange="modelCodeChanged(this.id)" id="mdlDrpDown_0">**

one last query:
Now all my select tags have name="mdlCode" as we used property="mdlCode" (whose type is String[])
On Form submission >> **Can i retrieve all the selected drop down values from formBean's getMdlCode() ?**

Comment: yes, you can get values by calling `getMdlCode()`, it'll return `String[]` and order of values stored in the array is the order of the `select` appears in the output.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The format of your styleId will produce ids like:

```
id="mdlDrpDown_+'1'" 
id="mdlDrpDown_+'2'"
```

You should write styleId like this:

```
styleId="mdlDrpDown_<%=ind %>"
```

then ids will be like:

```
id="mdlDrpDown_1" 
id="mdlDrpDown_2"
```

Comment: @ Brijesh:


I got error when tried: styleId="mdlDrpDown_<%=ind %>"
 

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
No getter method available for property mdlDrpDown_%=ind % for bean.




<%=ind> is not evaluated.

Comment: Then I tried:  styleId="<%=ind %>".

Error is:

JSPG0124E: Custom tag attribute styleId cannot be runtime expression. value: "[%=india %]"


it is same in the tld file also.

Comment: @Vishnu300 Not aware about this Exception. But I think scriptlet cannot help you here.

Comment: Yes..Can we keep scriptlet variable in pageScope and then use EL to append index dynamically here ?
I know very less of EL and JSTL so please help in this context..

Comment: @Vishnu300 <%=ind> is evaluating, you are getting exception because of dynamic property name, you are using `struts select` tag which means you must have getter and setter methods in `formbean` class.

Comment: @ Srinu: I used the name property="mdlCode" which has setter&getter in formBean. I have corrected it in question now..

The <%=ind> is not evaluated hence  got the error:


JSPG0124E: Custom tag attribute styleId cannot be runtime expression. value: "[%=india %]"

Comment: @Vishnu300 check my answer